# Breakdown SUM of INT by Each Month

Tags: t-sql

Query I use to find the total spend per station for a year. How do I break down the spend of each product by month i.e. each month as a column?

e.DT is a datetime, but only gets populated once a month.

```
select s.StationID, sum(e.Spend)
from Station s with(nolock)
join Expenditure e with(nolock)
on e.ProductID = s.ProductID
where e.DT between '1 JAN 18' and '1 DEC 18'
group by s.StationID
order by sum(e.Spend) desc
```

Comment: Would you accept a solution where each month is a _row_?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to report your month/year data points as separate *rows*, rather than columns.  I suggest the following query:

```
SELECT
    s.StationID,
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, e.DT, 120), 7) AS ym,
    SUM(e.Spend) AS total_spend
FROM Station s WITH(nolock)
INNER JOIN Expenditure e WITH(nolock)
    ON e.ProductID = s.ProductID
WHERE e.DT BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-01'
GROUP BY
    s.StationID,
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, e.DT, 120), 7)
ORDER BY
    s.StationID,
    SUM(e.Spend) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with PIVOT this way:

```
select ProductID, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
from (
    select Spend, month(DT) m, ProductID
    from Expenditure
    where DT between '1 JAN 18' and '1 DEC 18'
)  r
PIVOT
( sum(Spend)
    for m in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
)
 AS PivotTable;
```